# Why am I getting the error "non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" for this request?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error :
`"Error 102 : non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"`
for this request :

```
DECLARE @num_dossiers TABLE (num_dossier INT,indice NVARCHAR(3))
insert into @num_dossiers
select num_dossier,indice from dossier where num_sec=57

delete from constitue where (num_dossier,indice) in select (num_dossier,indice) from @num_dossiers
```

The request triggering the error is the last one :

```
delete from constitue where (num_dossier,indice) in select (num_dossier,indice) from @num_dossiers
```

What could be the cause of this error ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support a multi-column IN clause (unlike Oracle).

```
delete 
from constitue 
where (num_dossier,indice) in select (num_dossier,indice) from @num_dossiers
```

This can be rewritten as a EXISTS:

```
DELETE c
FROM constitue c
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM @num_dossiers nd WHERE n.num_dossier = c.num_dossier AND n.indice = c.indice);
```

Comment: You can express support for this (currently unplanned) prospect here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32894992-add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructo